# Break terraform aws_rds_cluster replication in the Cross Region Cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-aurora

Using Terraform, I am able to successfully create a RDS cluster using the following config in Region 1 -

```
resource "aws_rds_cluster" "aurora_cluster" {

    cluster_identifier              = "${var.environment_name}-aurora-cluster"
    database_name                   = "mydb"
    master_username                 = "${var.rds_master_username}"
    master_password                 = "${var.rds_master_password}"
    backup_retention_period         = 14
    final_snapshot_identifier       = "${var.environment_name}AuroraCluster"

    apply_immediately               = true
    db_cluster_parameter_group_name = "${aws_rds_cluster_parameter_group.default.name}"

    tags {
        Name         = "${var.environment_name}-Aurora-DB-Cluster"
        ManagedBy    = "terraform"
        Environment  = "${var.environment_name}"
    }

    lifecycle {
        create_before_destroy = true
    }
}

resource "aws_rds_cluster_instance" "aurora_cluster_instance" {

    count                 = "${length(split(",", var.multi_azs))}"

    identifier            = "${var.environment_name}-aurora-instance-${count.index}"
    cluster_identifier    = "${aws_rds_cluster.aurora_cluster.id}"
    instance_class        = "db.t2.small"
    publicly_accessible   = true
    apply_immediately     = true

    tags {
        Name         = "${var.environment_name}-Aurora-DB-Instance-${count.index}"
        ManagedBy    = "terraform"
        Environment  = "${var.environment_name}"
    }

    lifecycle {
        create_before_destroy = true
    }
}

output "db_primary_cluster_arn" {
 rds_cluster.aurora_cluster.cluster_identifier}"
  value = "${"${format("arn:aws:rds:%s:%s:cluster:%s", "${var.db_region}", "${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}", "${aws_rds_cluster.aurora_cluster.cluster_identifier}")}"}"
}
```

and create a Cross Region replica using the below, in region 2 -

```
resource "aws_rds_cluster" "aurora_crr_cluster" {

    cluster_identifier            = "${var.environment_name}-aurora-crr-cluster"
    database_name                 = "mydb"
    master_username               = "${var.rds_master_username}"
    master_password               = "${var.rds_master_password}"
    backup_retention_period       = 14
    final_snapshot_identifier     = "${var.environment_name}AuroraCRRCluster"
    apply_immediately             = true

    # Referencing to the primary region's cluster
    replication_source_identifier = "${var.db_primary_cluster_arn}"

    tags {
        Name         = "${var.environment_name}-Aurora-DB-CRR-Cluster"
        ManagedBy    = "terraform"
        Environment  = "${var.environment_name}"
    }

    lifecycle {
        create_before_destroy = true
    }

}

resource "aws_rds_cluster_instance" "aurora_crr_cluster_instance" {

    count                 = "${length(split(",", var.multi_azs))}"

    identifier            = "${var.environment_name}-aurora-crr-instance-${count.index}"
    cluster_identifier    = "${aws_rds_cluster.aurora_crr_cluster.id}"
    instance_class        = "db.t2.small"
    publicly_accessible   = true
    apply_immediately     = true

    tags {
        Name         = "${var.environment_name}-Aurora-DB-Instance-${count.index}"
        ManagedBy    = "terraform"
        Environment  = "${var.environment_name}"
    }

    lifecycle {
        create_before_destroy = true
    }

}
```

When I want to promote the Cross Region Replica in Region 2 to a stand alone cluster - I try to remove the replication source (replication_source_identifier) from the Cross Region RDS Cluster and do "terraform apply". I see that the output from Terraform says -

```
module.db_replica.aws_rds_cluster.aurora_crr_cluster: Modifying... (ID: dev-aurora-crr-cluster)
  replication_source_identifier: "arn:aws:rds:us-east-2:account_nbr:cluster:dev-aurora-cluster" => ""
module.db_replica.aws_rds_cluster.aurora_crr_cluster: Modifications complete after 1s (ID: dev-aurora-crr-cluster)

Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 1 changed, 0 destroyed.
```

But, I see "NO CHANGE" happening to the cross region cluster on the AWS console. I still see that the replication source is existing and same and the cross region cluster is NOT updated to a "standalone" in AWS.

If I try to do the same thing via the AWS CLI -

```
aws rds promote-read-replica-db-cluster --db-cluster-identifier="dev-aurora-crr-cluster" --region="us-west-1"
```

I see that the change is triggered immediately and the Cross Region Replica is promoted to a stand alone cluster. Does anyone know where I may be doing things wrong?
 or Terraform does not support promoting Cross Regional Replica's to standalone clusters. Please advice.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue